# Disable info messages in boto3 SNS python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, boto3, amazon-sns

I am using logging python package to log my errors messages

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='messages.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('some message')
```

it is writing my custom log messages to messages.log file working fine,

when I started using boto3 SNS library 
when I publish messages to SNS, again

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

above extra line was writing to messages.log file automatically

I think by default logging package adding info messages to messages.log file correct me if I am wrong.

Is it really info messages are coming from boto3 SNS package ?? if yes,  how to disable this info & warning messages that are coming from boto3 SNS package ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, i got the answer from GitHub, if anyone wants answer please refer below link

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1248#issuecomment-326049463